# In dplyr group_by() + summarise(sum)is not working

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

This is my code:

```
df <- structure(list(NOME = c("JOGADOR 1", "JOGADOR 1", "JOGADOR 6", 
"JOGADOR 6", "JOGADOR 5", "JOGADOR 5", "JOGADOR 3", "JUGADOR 3", 
"JOGADOR 9", "JOGADOR 9", "JOGADOR 7", "JOGADOR 7", "JOGADOR 8", 
"JOGADOR 8", "JOGADOR 10", "JOGADOR 10", "JOGADOR 4", "JOGADOR 4", 
"JOGADOR 2", "JOGADOR 2", "JOGADOR 12", "JOGADOR 11", "JOGADOR 13"
), TOTAL_MINUTES = c(48.15, 43, 48.15, 51.9333333333333, 48.15, 
51.9333333333333, 48.15, 51.9333333333333, 48.15, 25, 48.15, 
51.9333333333333, 48.15, 29, 48.15, 42, 48.15, 51.9333333333333, 
48.15, 51.9333333333333, 17, 26, 9), TOTAL.DISTANCE = c(5264L, 
3999L, 5242L, 5589L, 5684L, 5966L, 4833L, 5012L, 5013L, 2653L, 
5452L, 5691L, 5041L, 3775L, 5266L, 4321L, 4795L, 4924L, 5209L, 
5242L, 2085L, 2703L, 1282L)), row.names = c(NA, -23L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Its a simple task but its not working:

```
df %>%group_by(NOME) %>% 
  summarise(across(TOTAL_MINUTES:TOTAL.DISTANCE),sum())
```

It just reapting the `NOME` column values. Its not summing and giving one line per "JOGADOR X".

Why? Any help?

Answer (score 3):

The `across` was closed without the `sum`.  Also, if we are not providing any lambda expression, we don't use `sum()`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(NOME) %>% 
  summarise(across(TOTAL_MINUTES:TOTAL.DISTANCE, sum, 
            na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 14 × 3
   NOME       TOTAL_MINUTES TOTAL.DISTANCE
   <chr>              <dbl>          <int>
 1 JOGADOR 1           91.2           9263
 2 JOGADOR 10          90.2           9587
 3 JOGADOR 11          26             2703
 4 JOGADOR 12          17             2085
 5 JOGADOR 13           9             1282
 6 JOGADOR 2          100.           10451
 7 JOGADOR 3           48.2           4833
 8 JOGADOR 4          100.            9719
 9 JOGADOR 5          100.           11650
10 JOGADOR 6          100.           10831
11 JOGADOR 7          100.           11143
12 JOGADOR 8           77.2           8816
13 JOGADOR 9           73.2           7666
14 JUGADOR 3           51.9           5012
```

---

Or using `lambda` expression

```
df %>%
  group_by(NOME) %>% 
  summarise(across(TOTAL_MINUTES:TOTAL.DISTANCE, ~sum(.x, 
            na.rm = TRUE)), .groups = 'drop')
```

Comment: so sorry. Thanks for your time.